# How to hide the day and month drop down lists for a DateType Field type in Symfony form

Tags: twig, symfony

I have this in a Symfony3 form:

```
->add('target_date', DateType::class, array(
    'mapped' => false,
    'format' => 'dd MMM y',
    'label' => 'year:',
    'label_attr' => array(
       'id' => 'target_date',
    ),
    'years' => range(2025,2017,1),
))
```

And I want to hide the day and month values so that only the year appears.

Comment: have you tried with `format => 'y'` and `'widget' => 'choice'` as described in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#years)?

Comment: Hi there @Matteo . Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I tried that previously. What happens when you use `'format' => 'y'` is it shows invalid option exception: `The "format" option should contain the letters "y", "M" and "d". Its current value is "y".` I also tried 'yyyy' same thing. It needs all of 'd' 'm' and 'y'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using Twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.target_date['day'],{'attr':{'style':'display:none'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.target_date['month'],{'attr':{'style':'display:none'}}) }}
```

The entry `form.target_date['day']` refers to the day drop-down list of the target_date element.